# How to make console2 open in a specific folder?

Tags: console2

With cmd, I can do

```
cmd /K cd /D "c:\repo"
```

to open cmd in c:\repo

How to do the same with console2 when using cmd as a shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the command line options help:

```
 -d <directory> 

 Specifies a startup directory. If you want to parametrize
 startup dirs, you need to specify startup directory parameter as "%1"\
 (backslash is outside of the double quotes)
```

Answer (score 8):

In 2.00b147, navigate to `Edit -> Settings -> Console` and enter your desired directory in the `Startup dir` field.

Comment: How do you set that field to be "The current directory"? -- i.e. setting it to `%CD%` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer but I found this to be even more convenient:
https://github.com/kodLite/cppStartingKitProject-Guide/blob/master/source/Console_2--Usage--Open_Console_Here.rst

This adds an option to the right-click menu to open in that specific folder.
Won't work in combination with the "Startup dir""setting though!

**Update:**
Changing the reg a bit will make it even better (open selected folder in Console as well)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Console2]
@="Open in Console2"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Console2\command]
@="C:\\Path\\To\\Console\\2\\Console2.exe -d %0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Console2]
@="Open Console2 Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Console2\command]
@="C:\\Path\\To\\Console\\2\\Console2.exe"
```